# Mobile upload using a different image button immediately after selecting image?

Tags: css, file-io, upload

I would like to use my own .png image to trigger a

```
<input type="file" id="pictureCapture" accept="image/*; capture=camera" />
```

and then instantly upload the image to an MVC controller.

So, the first question is how to replace the input tag with a clickable image?

And second, thus far, I've only seen file upload as a 2 part process.  You click the browse button, select your file, then click Upload to send the file.

How do I consolidate it so that right after you select the file, it uploads?

Is there a 3rd party control that does all this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

Html:

```
<input type="file" id="pictureCapture" accept="image/*; capture=camera" style="visibility:hidden;" />

<a href="#" id="uploadPhotoFromCamera"><img src="@(Url.Content("~/Images/Mobile/Camera.png"))" /></a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $("#uploadPhotoFromCamera").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#pictureCapture").trigger("click");
    });

    $('#pictureCapture').on("change", function () {
        var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object

        var fileInput = document.getElementById('pictureCapture');

        //Iterating through each files selected in fileInput
        for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
            //Appending each file to FormData object
            formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
        }

        //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '@(Url.Action("UploadMobile", "Document"))')
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert('success');
            }               
        }

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult UploadMobile()
{
    List<HttpPostedFileBase> files = new List<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        files.Add(Request.Files[i]); //Uploaded file
    }

    // Do whatever now with your list of files

    return Json("Uploaded " + Request.Files.Count + " files");
}
```